# Java: JFile to Save a file only opens first time

Tags: java, user-interface, jfilechooser

I call a method that opens JFileChooser and saves a file somewhere. However, this dialog that allows the user to save a file only opens the first time the user calls it. If, while program is running, the user calls the method again - nothing happens. The whole program freezes (it does not quit, though). No errors are being displayed.

Here is my code for the method (the program is large, I cannot share the whole):

```
public static String loadGlosFilManuell() throws IOException {
    String readThisGlos = null;
    try {           
        fileChooser1.setDialogTitle("Choose");;
        int userSelection1 = fileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (userSelection1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File fileToOpen1 = fileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
            readThisGlos = fileToOpen1.getAbsolutePath();
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(readThisGlos);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            loadNamn = bufferedReader.readLine();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } else {
            //Error
        }
    } catch (HeadlessException | NullPointerException e) {
        //Error
    }
    return readThisGlos;
}
```

Comment: The file chooser might be hidden behind the main frame. You shouldn't pass null to showOpenDialog(). You should pass the parent component.

Comment: *the program is large, I cannot share the whole*: then post a minimal but complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet What do you mean with the parent component? Could you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have written a double `;`:

Change

```
 fileChooser1.setDialogTitle("Choose");;
```

to

```
 fileChooser1.setDialogTitle("Choose");
```

It is quite astonishing that the editor you are using did not give you an error.

Comment: Oh! *facepalm* Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't have any impact whatsoever.

Comment: @JBNizet It actually did.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, there are cases where a double semicolon does produce an error, For instance:
`public int method() {
   return 1;;
} ` Because the program is too large to share, it might have an influence.

Comment: @Ainvox No, it didn't. Maybe you introduced another change after removing it and recompiling. But the generated byte-code, with or without this additional semi-colon, is exactly the same.

Comment: @MouradKourie in that example: the code wouldn't **compile**, because the noop instruction before the last semi-colon is unreachable.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, you are right. I apologize for my answer. In what way did it work for you Ainvox? Did you change anything else?